# MPI_Scatter values with repetitions

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpich, intel-mpi

For example I have 6 MPI nodes forming a 1D grid.
On the master process I have some values for the edges of the grid:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

And I want to distribute these values to put each value to both nodes that are adjacent to the corresponding edge. That is, I want to get the following data distribution among the nodes:

```
1 | 1 2 | 2 3 | 3 4 | 4 5 | 5
```

What is the best way to perform this? Seems that this cannot be done with a single `MPI_Scatter` call.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/25813593/620382

Comment: @Zulan, thanks for the link. Though, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I just wonder if it is possible to somehow tamper with MPI_Datatypes and create a self-overlapping type which could be scattered in an overlapping manner.

Comment: You will be interested by the DMDA structure of the Petsc library. In particular, tools related to structured grids are detailed in pages 49+ of the [manual](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manual.pdf). Take a look at the concept of ghost nodes and see if it helps. See [DMDACreate1d](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/DM/DMDACreate1d.html).

Comment: Thanks, @francis! Seems that DMDA structure has this sort of overlapping. It would be interesting to have a look at petsc source code and see how they have implemented the communications.