# MPI Scatterv changes ranks

Tags: c++, mpi

My goal here is to get a Matrix(saved in a vector) distributed to N Processors. 
Since the distributed chunks are overlapping, I wanted to use the MPI_Scatterv function.

However, after the call every rank is set to zero, and after That I get an mpi error code 11(SegFault)

To test that, I printed the ranks. At hello0, the ranks are 0,1,2,3 but at hello2 they change to 0,0,0,0

TBH I'm not sure, how correct my code is overall, but the problem is gone when commenting out the MPI_Scatter function call.

Code:

```
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    //Matrix is NxN
    int N = 16;

    //ghostlines(How many overlapping lines)
    int X = 1;

    //basic chunk size
    int rsize = (N * N / size);

    //bigger than need be
    std::vector<double> rbuff(2*rsize + 2 * X, 0);

    std::cout << "hallo0 "<<rank<<std::endl;

    //is filled with some random numbers before being sent
    std::vector<double> v1(N * N, X0);

    // For N=16, size = 4, X=1 
    // sizes = {65, 66, 66, 65} 
    // disps = {0, 62, 124, 186}
    MPI_Scatterv(v1.data(), sizes, disps, MPI_DOUBLE, &rbuff, sizes[rank], MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    std::cout << "hallo2 "<<rank<<std::endl;
```

Comment: `rbuff.data()` or `&rbuff[0]` instead of `&rbuff`.

Comment: I am afraid that you are going to face trouble. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813593/use-mpi-scatterv-to-scatter-overlapping-regions-of-an-array , in particular the answer of Jonathan Dursi : sending overlapping segments is forbidden by the mpi standards. `The specification of counts, types, and displacements should not cause any location on the root to be read more than once.` ([mpi standards 3.1 ](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf), section 5.6 Scatter, on page 192. The answer of Jonathan Dursi already details the alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use MPI\_Scatterv to Scatter Overlapping Regions of an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813593/use-mpi-scatterv-to-scatter-overlapping-regions-of-an-array)